# How to use react hook form with component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to integrate react-hook-form with my prebuild component but its says register is not a funtion

Here is my code:
main.js // Main file

```
<div>
    <MyInputText title={'Driver Name'} label={'drivername'} register={register}/>
    </div>
```

Component File

```
import React from 'react'

function MyInputText(props, {register}) {
  console.log('props', props.register);
  return (
    <label className="block">
      <span>{props.title}</span>
      <input
        {...props.register(props.label)}
        className="form-input mt-1.5 w-full rounded-lg border border-slate-300 bg-transparent px-3 py-2 placeholder:text-slate-400/70 hover:border-slate-400 focus:border-primary dark:border-navy-450 dark:hover:border-navy-400 dark:focus:border-accent"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        type={props.tyoe}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
    </label>
  );
}

export default MyInputText
```

Error

[image]

Comment: MyInputText({ register }) -  this is the correct way to extract values from props.

Comment: Already tried, It gives the same error @mirik999

Comment: What is the output of console.log(register) in main.js ?

Comment: I created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-worker-5vkz1m?file=/src/App.js) and was unable to recreate your issue. Please share a codesandbox where you encounter the isse

Comment: as I can see you have placed both main.js and component in a single file, I have created it in separate files @RubenSmn

Comment: @mirik999 In main.js I am getting function as console but when I log register in component I get the function in props log, But When I try to use props.register Its says props.register is not a function, I have already added the image with the logs

Comment: File separation does not matter @Suraj I updated the codesandbox. Can you provide a sandbox where you encounter the issue?

Comment: @RubenSmn I have tried your sandbox, and now Everything is working fine, Thanks for the help, Add your comment as an answer so that I can tick that.